# PHP rss reader doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, facebook, rss

Hey I wrote this to grab get a FB page feed and output it to a site.

It works just fine from my localhost, but not when placed it on the server. It's just blank.

```
<?php
$xml_url = "http://fbrss.com/f/7f823b5ba0557decbd324199136326ac_7LpQh7MAJ22MISS1omjI.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);

$json = json_encode($xml);
$objects = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$object = $objects;

$i=0;
foreach ($object as $items) {
    $json = json_encode($items);
    $objects = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    $object = $objects;
    $i=0;
    foreach ($object as $items) {
        $item[$i] = $items;
        $i++;
    }

}
$entries = $item[5];
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo '<a href="'.$entry["guid"].'">', substr($entry["title"], 0, 50), '...</a><br /><span>', substr($entry["pubDate"], 4, 18),'</span><br /><hr /><br />';
}   
?>
```

My questions are 1) why doent it work live, and 2) is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Ok I have pulled the error log, and this is what I am getting:

[Mon Jun 25 03:08:20 2012][debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 74.192.47.34] Zlib: Compressed 0 to 2 : URL /****/****/xmlFeed.php  (* added by me)

So... its a compression issue? What does it mean, and what can I do?

Comment: A blank page usually means there's an error somewhere. Your server logs will show what it is. My first guess would be that your server is on a version of PHP lower than 5.2, which would make `json_encode`/`json_decode` fail.

Comment: if that's the case... what might be a good work around?

Comment: Figure out what the error is. If that's the problem, find a webhost with a proper version of PHP.

Comment: I am working on Network Solutions for a client, so I will need a work around... it is looking like they have PHP 5.0, which is unfortunate.

Comment: If your host isn't on 5.3 by now, it's time to run away. Heh. Apparently there's a PECL module you can maybe install, but I doubt Network Solutions gives you enough access to install it.

Comment: ok... I am running 5.2.4, but phpinfo says "'--disable-json'" under Configure Command. is that whats tripping it up?

Comment: But, why do you want to use `JSON` to parse this feed? You load the feed via simplexml. Can't you just parse it as xml and get your results. No need for json at all here imo.

Comment: I was having trouble getting at the arrays in the FB XML. the jason technique was something that I read would pull an array out of an xml.

Comment: Ok, let me try to get it done via the simplexml thing only..

Comment: Hi, i have posted a xml only solution. See if it works.

Comment: I have placed new information in the post above. My error log is showing "Zlib: Compressed 0 to 2" error. What is that all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will work.

```
<?php
$xml_url = "http://fbrss.com/f/7f823b5ba0557decbd324199136326ac_7LpQh7MAJ22MISS1omjI.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<a href="'.$item->guid.'">', substr($item->title, 0, 50), '...</a><br /><span>', substr($item->pubDate, 4, 18),'</span><br /><hr /><br />';
}
?>
```

Short, sweet, simple.

Comment: I love it!!! ($xml->channel->item was what was throwing me.) Whats driving me nuts though, is though this solution is nice and tidy, it still is not working on the netsol server :(

Comment: Oh...then JSON is not the only culprit. Can you do a `phpinfo()` on your server's web page and check if `simplexml` is enabled, else, you can open your command line on the server and type `php -m` to see the list of installed extensions. See if `simplexml` is one of them.

Comment: Revision $Revision: 314376 $
Schema support enabled

Comment: This would mean simplexml is enabled, right? and still you are unable to get it going...then you need to contact your server admins to figure the issue.

Comment: np...hope you get your solution :)